# Scala - converting array to map

Tags: scala

I have an array like this

```
(20140101,20140102,20140103,20140104,20140105,20140106,20140107,20140108)
```

I want to create a map from this by prefixing each value with "s3://" and concatenating three values with a comma.

Output:

```
val params = Map("1"-> "s3://20140101,s3://20140102,s3://20140103","2"-> "s3://20140104,s3://20140105,s3://20140106","3"->"s3://20140107,s3://20140108")
```

I'm a beginner and kindly request some thoughts here.

Comment: Are you saying you want a maximum of 3 s3 urls per map group?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This returns a `Map[Int, Array[String]]`. If you really want the values as a `String`, then use `mapValues(_.mkString(","))` on the result.

```
scala> val xs = Array(20140101,20140102,20140103,20140104,20140105,20140106,20140107,20140108)          
xs: Array[Int] = Array(20140101, 20140102, 20140103, 20140104, 20140105, 20140106, 20140107, 20140108)

scala> xs.map(x => "s3://" + x).grouped(3).zipWithIndex.map(t => (t._2, t._1)).toMap
res16: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Array[String]] = Map(0 -> Array(s3://20140101, s3://20140102, s3://20140103), 1 -> Array(s3://20140104, s3://20140105, s3://20140106), 2 -> Array(s3://20140107, s3://20140108))
```

Answer (score 5):

I think this will do what you want:

```
  val array = Array(20140101, 20140102, 20140103, 20140104, 20140105, 20140106, 20140107, 20140108)
  val result = array.
    sliding(3, 3). // this selects 3 elements at a time and steps 3 elements at a time
    zipWithIndex. // this adds an index to the 3 elements
    map({ case (arr, i) => (i + 1).toString -> arr.map(a => "s3://" + a.toString).mkString(",")}). // this makes a tuple and concats the array elements
    toMap // this transforms the Array of tuples into a map

  println(result) 
  //prints Map(1 -> s3://20140101,s3://20140102,s3://20140103, 2 -> s3://20140104,s3://20140105,s3://20140106, 3 -> s3://20140107,s3://20140108)
```

Comment: Great! I would put `.view` before all the operations so that new arrays won't be created every time

Comment: `view` is a strange beast, and it's implementation makes me not want to use it as it seems non-deterministic. With that said, I tried it and got this error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.SeqViewLike$$anon$1 cannot be cast to scala.collection.mutable.IndexedSeqView`

Comment: Oh that's actually strange.. Could you convert the array in the first line and try the operation?

Comment: Converting `toList` works, but doesn't that defeat the purpose of using the `view`?

Comment: I mean wrapping the array with `scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray`. It only costs an instantiation, O(1). Just define `val array` as `val array: IndexedSeq[Int]`. It worked in my REPL :)

Answer (score 1):

Just another variation, this time avoiding zipWithIndex and the key value swap

```
val xs = Array(20140101,20140102,20140103,20140104,20140105,20140106,20140107,20140108)

Iterator.from(0).zip{xs.grouped(3).map{"s://"+ _.mkString(",")}}.toMap
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to a tuple then turn that tuple into a map. Like this:

```scala
val xs = Array(20140101,20140102,20140103,20140104,20140105,20140106,20140107,20140108)

val xsMap = ((1 to (xs.length + 1))
    zip xs.map(valueAtIndex => "s://" + valueAtIndex)).toMap
```

This won't be particularly fast but it is simple and makes sense.
Note: I only tested this will the new scala3 compiler: dotty. The scala version I am using is 3.0.1.